# How to draw a bar-in-bar chart using Mathematica? or align two bar/rectangle charts at the center of the bar rather than the left alignment?

Tags: charts, alignment

I would like to create a bar-in-bar chart similar to the online example provided below.

[image]

I have attempted to create it using the "RectangleChart" function to generate two bars. However, when I combine the two bars, the "Show" function produces a result with incorrect positioning, as shown here. Could you please guide me on how to resolve this alignment issue?

[image]

Comment: Please give us data to work with and include Mathematica code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Syed Thanks for your comment. This is a toy example for illustration of the problem. The admin has gave me a viable solution. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, let me try with some fake data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
alist = RandomInteger[{20000, 45 10^3}, 4];
blist = RandomInteger[{20000, 45 10^3}, 4];

legend = SwatchLegend[{
    Opacity[1, Lighter@Red]
    , Opacity[1, Blend[{Lighter@Cyan, Gray}]]}
   , {"Profit 2016", "Profit 2017"}
   , LegendLabel -> Style["Year", Bold, 12]
   ];

b1 = BarChart[{{2, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, BarOrigin -> Left, 
   Ticks -> None, 
   ChartStyle -> {Lighter@Red, Blend[{Lighter@Cyan, Gray}]
     , Blend[{Lighter@Cyan, Gray}]}
   , BarSpacing -> {0.2, 0.5}
   , ImageSize -> 30
   ];

xlabel = Row[{"Profitability", "   ", b1}];    
    
xTicks = Transpose@{Range[0, 45000, 5000], 
        Table[ToString@i <> "k", {i, 0, 45, 5}]};

Legended[
 Show@MapThread[
   BarChart[
     #1
     , BarOrigin -> Left
     , BarSpacing -> #2
     , ChartStyle -> #3
     , Axes -> {True, True}
     , Ticks -> {True, None}
     , ChartLabels -> #4
     , PlotRangePadding -> 0.5
     , GridLines -> {Range[0, 45000, 5000], None}
     , GridLinesStyle -> {{Dotted, Gray}, None}
     , Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}
     , FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {xTicks, None}}
     , FrameLabel -> #5
     , ImageSize -> 500
     , PlotRange -> {{-10000, 50000}, Automatic}
     ] &,
   {{alist, blist}
    , {0.4, 1.4}
    , {Directive[EdgeForm[None], Opacity[1, Lighter@Red]]
     , Directive[EdgeForm[None], 
      Opacity[1, Blend[{Lighter@Cyan, Gray}]]]
     }
    , {None, 
     Style[# <> "      ", Bold, Black, 12, 
        FontFamily -> "Calibri"] & /@ {"South", "Central", "East", 
       "West"}}
    , {{None, xlabel}, None}
    }
   ]
 , Placed[legend, {0.9, 0.2}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks again for your solution. I'm trying to learn from both solutions. Many thanks again!

Comment: Finally, I notice the key of this problem. The Barchart function works automatically with a centered position when overlapping two plots. We can use barspacing to control the width of the bars. However, I tried to use the RectangleChart function to generate a bar-in-bar chart, but it doesn't support the automatically centered function.

Comment: Mathematica has more mystery locks than users have keys for. I learn new stuff everyday.

Answer (score 9):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[{5, 40}, {10, 2}];
```

First, a helper function to pre-process input data to add metadata to be used for scaling bar widths:

```
preProcess = Map[Thread[# -> 1/Range[Length@#]/2] &];
```

and a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) that modifies the box coordinates using attached metadata:

```
cEF[cedf_ : "Rectangle"] := ChartElementData[cedf][{#[[1]], 
     Mean[#[[2]]] + {-1, 1} #3[[1]]}, ##2] &;
```

We can then use `BarChart` with the options [`BarSpacing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarSpacing.html), [`BarOrigin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarOrigin.html) and the custom function `cEF` as the setting for the option `ChartElementFunction`

```
BarChart[preProcess @ data, 
 BarSpacing -> {-1, .5}, 
 BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartStyle -> {Lighter @ Red, Darker @ Cyan},
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF[], 
 ChartLabels -> {ToUpperCase@Alphabet[], None}, 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{"2021", "2022"}, 
    LegendLabel -> Placed["legend:", Before], LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
   Above], 
 LabelStyle -> 14,
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Use `ChartElementFunction -> cEF["GlassRectangle"]` to get

[image]

Use `ChartElementFunction -> cEF["ArrowRectangle"]` to get

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];
data2 = RandomInteger[{5, 40}, {4, 5}];

BarChart[preProcess @ data2,
  BarSpacing -> {-1, .25},
  BarOrigin -> Left,
  ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
  ChartElementFunction -> cEF[], 
  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], 
  ChartLabels -> {{"SOUTH", "CENTRAL", "EAST", "WEST"}, None}, 
  ChartLegends -> 
    Placed[SwatchLegend[{"2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023"}, 
      LegendLabel -> Placed["legend:", Before], 
      LegendLayout -> "Row"], Above], 
 LabelStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt response for my questions. The customized function works perfect for this issue. Thanks again kglr!

Answer (score 3):

We can also use a custom [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) that post-processes `BarChart` output to rescale rectangle groups:

```
centerRectangleGroups = Replace[#, 
    p : {{_Directive, _[_[_Rectangle, ___], ___]} ..} :> 
     MapIndexed[Scale[#, {1, 1/#2[[1]]}] &, p], All] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];

data = RandomInteger[{5, 40}, {4, 2}];

chartstyle = {Lighter @ Red, Darker @ Cyan};

legendlabels = Range[2021, 2022];

options = {
   DisplayFunction -> centerRectangleGroups,
   BarSpacing -> {-1, .25},
   BarOrigin -> Left,
   ChartStyle -> chartstyle,
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[],
   ChartLabels -> {{"SOUTH", "CENTRAL", "EAST", "WEST"}, None},
   ChartLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[legendlabels,
      LegendLabel -> Placed["Year:", Before], LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
     Above],
   LabelStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 500
   };


BarChart[data, options]
```

[image]

Replace `data = RandomInteger[{5, 40}, {4, 2}];` with `data = RandomInteger[{5, 40}, {4, 5}];`, `chartstyle = {Lighter@Red, Darker@Cyan};` with `chartstyle = "Rainbow"` and `legendlabels = Range[2021, 2022];` with `legendlabels = Range[2019, 2023];` above to get

[image]